# Parse output of a perl script run from within a python script

Tags: python, perl

I have a perl script which i would like to run from within a Python script. Currently, when I run the per script from command prompt I get a small log.

I want to run this script from within the python script and get the log(maybe to a .txt file). Then i would want to further open this txt file and search and parse some values to continue further in my program.

So how can I invoke the perl script to run and the log be collected in a txt file. Then open this text file and search for a string and value.

Lets say the log output is:

"total time: 72"

I would like to extract the value 72 doing all of this and then use it in my program

The perl script also has to have input parameters while invoking it. For ex: perl duration.pl -x some_value1 -y some_value2

Comment: Could you please show us your code. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for detailed description.

Comment: You can use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run the Perl script from Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example assuming the Perl script produces a single line of output on the form `total time: 72` :

```
import re
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["perl", "duration.pl", "-x", "8", "-y", "9"], check=True)
with open("result.txt") as fh:
    line = fh.readline()  # assume the script produces a single line output

match_object = re.search(r"total time:\s+(\d+)", line)
if match_object:
    result = match_object.group(1)
```

**Edit**:

The `subprocess.run()` function was introduced in Python 3.5, if you have an older version you can use `subprocess.call()` instead:

```
subprocess.call(["perl", "duration.pl", "-x", "8", "-y", "9"])
```

**Edit 2**:

To redirect output to a file when running the Perl script, you can invoke the shell from `subprocess.call()` like this:

```
subprocess.call(["perl duration.pl -x 8 -y 9 > result.txt"], shell=True)
```

Comment: get this error, perl.py", line 4, in <module>
    subprocess.run(["perl", "duration_calc.pl", "-vht", "-bc", "100", "-bw", "20
", "-nss", "1"])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: Which python version  are you using? Then `subprocess.run()` function was added in Python 3.5

Comment: Version 2.7.2, I think subprocess.call() works in this one, could you tell me how to write the output of this perl script to txt file. For ex in command line I would do something like this perl duration.pl > log.txt

Comment: right now with this code it says: "perl.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open("result.txt") as fh:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'result.txt'

Comment: this worked: subprocess.call("perl duration.pl -x 8 -y 9 > result.txt", shell=True)